# Defining Model for Gson with extra attributes

Tags: android, json, model, gson

I'm defining models for Gson serialization/deserialization and I'm trying to figure out the best way given my particular JSON response.

Each API call in my app is of a similar format:

- status: status of the call
- message: a message if above status is 'error'
- data: any data the user asked for

In my model, I really only care about the data. For instance, if user calls /get_buddies, I just want to get a list of all the buddies. But I also 'care' about the status too, right? If the status is 'error' for some reason (user isn't logged in, or something), I want to tell the user that and Toast the message (that's a bad example, as it'd never happen)...

How do I create my model so that I can read status and message, but so that if I package this model as JSON to *send*, I don't package those up.

My first thought from my research is to have a class called GetBuddiesCall

```
public class GetBuddiesCall {
    String status;
    String message;
    ArrayList<Buddy> buddies;
}
```

and then a class Buddy

```
public class Buddy {
    String username;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    // etc.
}
```

Then, Gson will look at these two models and be able to deserialize accordingly. Then, when attempting to serialize, I only use the Buddy model as the status and message aren't necessary for client -> server communication. Is there a better way than this? I know that there are modifiers you can use like transient, which keeps Gson from looking at that field when packaging up a JSON.

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: You can exclude fields from serialization by using the transient keyword, but I think this might apply for both converting to/from json.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

1. Using `@Expose` annotation explicitly for all fields, you can select if each field should be just serialized, just deserialized or both. Note that this also requires `GsonBuilder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()` to be set.
   https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.html
2. Define a custom exclusion strategy: https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/ExclusionStrategy.html

   In the simplest form such an implementation could hard-code fields to skip; a more advanced but also flexible approach would be to also define your own custom annotation and have the exclusion strategy check for its presence for each field, e.g. it could be something like `@ReadOnly` or `@Exclude(read = true, write = false)`.

   Note that you can set excursion strategies per serialization and deserialization independently: https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#addDeserializationExclusionStrategy(com.google.gson.ExclusionStrategy)

If your project is small, using the `@Expose` annotation is definitely quickest. The back side of it is simply that it somewhat clutters the code.

Comment: This looks great, and exactly what I needed. I will look into both. I completely understand expose, and I think the ExclusionStrategy as well... I will check this as accepted once I ensure this strategy works for me. Thank you JHH!

Comment: My pleasure. Good luck.

Comment: If you look at the Exclusion Strategy documentation, they give the example of defining your own annotation (like you mention above), they do something like public @interface FooAnnotation and in the interface body they have a comment // some implementation here.. What would you put there? Why do you need to implement anything? In the Exclusion Strategy it just checks for fields with that annotation and ignores them, which makes sense, but I don't see what you would put in the actual annotation interface!

Comment: Annotations don't really have implementations, but they can have fields, making them parameterized annotations, as in my last example taking two booleans.

Comment: Come to think of it, I remember writing a general purpose exclusion strategy similar to my last example some time ago. I know I actually ran into some frustrating problems. Perhaps I should dig it up and publish it on github. :-) Not able to today though.

Comment: If you do, let me know! Either through this post or DM.. I've never DMd anybody on SO though :P